# How to get all the predefined do_action() calls from an active theme

Tags: filters, actions

To hook my plugin content into anywhere, suppose I offered the theme developers to create their own hooks with a prefix (`pre_`) anywhere in their theme - the rest of the hook is unknown to me. So what will they do?

Suppose, in `single.php` they placed a hook like:

```
do_action( 'pre_kauwa' );
```

in `page.php` they placed a hook like:

```
do_action( 'pre_kala' );
```

And so on...

How can I get all those `do_action()` declarations with a prefix `pre_` from an active WordPress installation (active theme)
**or,**
from an active WordPress viewport (post, page, archive *bla bla*)

...so that I can make a list of hooks dynamically where my content can be hooked using `add_action()`?

#### Testing testing...

In `wp-includes/plugin.php` I found the `has_filter()` function declaration. From there I took the following line for testing:

```
$wp_filter = $GLOBALS['wp_filter'];
$has = ! empty( $wp_filter[ $tag ] );
```

In my dummy theme's `index.php` after `the_content()` (within the loop) I placed:

```
do_action( 'pre_kk' );
```

Just after the `do_action()` call I placed:

```
$t_test = $GLOBALS['wp_filter'];
$hk = 'pre_kk';
var_dump( $t_test[$hk] );
```

But it's throwing an undefined index.

Comment: Do you do `add_action( 'pre_kk', 'your_function' )` to your `do_action( 'pre_kk' )`? Because otherwise - if I'm not totally mistaken - it won't be added to `$wp_filter`.

Comment: @ialocin you are right. +1 for that. But actually that couldn't solve my problem. It's returning the callback function, not the hook. :(

Comment: Because you're already addressing the specific element in the array. The first level are the hook names/tags. To get all your »pre_*« hooks you have to iterate and/or search through the array, there are plenty of threads how to do this on [so]. Or at least I don't know of a build-in functionality to do it with.

Comment: *The first level are the hook names/tags.* - though I'm not sure till now. I'll let you know the update.

Comment: The plugin Debug Objects give you all fired hooks in current page, also in front end. Maybe this helps you.

Comment: It sounds to me like you're trying to accomplish something akin to the goal of the [Theme Hook Alliance](https://github.com/zamoose/themehookalliance).

Answer (score 0):

`pre_` is a terrible prefix for this because it's going to interfere with all of the WordPress internal hooks that are prefixed with `pre_`.

But if you want to get the name of all the actions and filters called on a certain page you can use the `all` hook which adds your callback to every hook. Obviously this is terribly expensive so you wouldn't want to do it on a production server.

```
add_action( 'all', 'wpse_all_actions' );
function wpse_all_actions() {
  static $pre = [];
  $filter = current_filter();
  if( 'pre_' === substr( $filter, 0, 4 ) ) {
    $pre[] = $filter;
  }
  if( 'shutdown' === $filter ) {
    var_dump( $pre );
  }
}
```